# await is not working correctly for collection.insertMany()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert many records in my collection with `collection.insertMany()` and I made a test for it but unfortenly this test is not deterministic(**await** sometimes works sometimes not). Why I think so, because `collection.insertMany('Inserted ten rogues in collection')` sometimes diplayse after `console.log(queryResult)` which displays empty array what causes that my test sometimes fails sometimes pass. Why this **await** sometimes working sometimes not ?

My test:

```js
describe('Saving records', () => {
    it('Save single record in DB', async () => {
        const warrior1 = new Warrior({
            name: 'John',
            class: 'priest',
            age: 21,
            weight: 75
        });
        await warrior1.save();
        assert(warrior1.isNew === false);
    });
    it('Save multiple records in DB', async () => {
        const tenRogues = createTenRouges();
        await Warrior.collection.insertMany(tenRogues, (err, _docs) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Inserted ten rogues in collection');
            }
        });
        const queryResult = await Warrior.find({class: 'rogue'});
        console.log(queryResult);
        assert(queryResult.length === 10);
    });
});
```

CreateTenRogues method :

```js
function createTenRouges() {
    const warriors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        warriors.push(new Warrior({
            name: 'John',
            class: 'rogue',
            age: 21,
            weight: 75
        }));
    }
    return warriors;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a callback in your `insertMany()` call, that function will not return a `Promise`, so using `await` there does nothing.

Assuming that you want to use `async/await` over callbacks, you can use a `try/catch` block to do your error checking and then `await` will work properly:

```js
try {
  await Warrior.collection.insertMany(tenRogues);
  console.log('Inserted ten rogues in collection');
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but my test still sometimes pass sometimes not :/ 
test after changes :
```
it('Save multiple records in DB', async () => {
        const tenRogues = createTenRouges();
        try {
            await Warrior.collection.insertMany(tenRogues);
            console.log('Inserted ten rogues in collection');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        const queryResult = await Warrior.find({class: 'rogue'});
        assert(queryResult.length === 10);
    });```

Comment: What does your `createTenRogues()` function return? If it's a `Promise` you also need to `await` that.

Comment: No it is very simple function(no asynchronous), but if you want to see this function I can add to question ?

Comment: hmm it is wierd but now(maybe after 10min) i rerun this test around 30 times and it is passing all the time, I do not know why it was not working immediately but it seems working now. Thank you for your answer mate